Do all EVM chains use the same minimum transaction gas of 21000?
Do all EVM chain use 21,000 gas as a minimum transaction gas for simple ETH payments?
Optimism seems to do so. How about the other EVM chains?

Related: see Matt Solomon's cast.

No, not all EVM chains use 21,000 as a minimum transaction gas, and unfortunately, there's no universal explanation for why this is so.
Each chain has implemented a unique gas metering system suited to its custom EVM architecture.
Examples of simple ETH payment transactions for three different chains:

Optimism: 21,000 gas
Arbitrum: 37,051 gas
zkSync: variable, typically between 120k and 190k

Documentation references:

Optimism: Transaction Fees
Arbitrum: Gas/ Fees
zkSync: Fee Model

zkSync is the most complicated fee model of the bunch. Gas consumption fluctuates a lot due to their bespoke VM design, especially (i) native Account Abstraction and (ii) state diffs. For example, two consecutive simple ETH transfers on zkSync cost 183k gas and 124k gas.
From zkSync's docs:

Ethereum has a constant of 21000 gas that covers the intrinsic costs of processing a transaction, i.e. checking the signature and updating the nonce for the account.
On zkSync Era this varies because we support custom and paymaster accounts. These accounts require a (usually) higher amount of gas than EOAs.

